# Keep overflow:hidden behavior after will-change:transform

Tags: css, will-change

I have a parent and a child elements:

```
.parent {
  will-change: transform;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.child {
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  left: 80px;
}
```

without `will-change:transform` style, `.child` element regardless of parent's position and `overflow:hidden` will be positioned based on window.
Now that the `.parent` has this style, not only `top` and `left` of `.child` calculate from `.parent`, but also `overflow:hidden` applies on `.child` too.
It seems that `position:fixed` will be totally ignored if we add `will-change:transform`
**Take a look here: https://jsbin.com/beluweroti/1/edit?html,css,output**

**Note:** I don't add this style to `.parent`, so I cannot simply remove it.

I can deal with positioning, and set correct `left` and `top`, but the question is
how can I ignore `overflow:hidden` for fixed-positioned children?

Comment: you can overwrite this property by setting `will-change: initial` to `.parent`.

Comment: no, I cannot, parent needs it to boost performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-will-change/#will-change):

> If any non-initial value of a property would cause the element **to generate a containing block for fixed positioned elements**, specifying that property in will-change must cause the element to generate a containing block for fixed positioned elements

So basically you are facing the issue with transform and not the will-change because:

> For elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model, any value other than none for the transform property also causes the element to establish a containing block for all descendants. Its padding box will be used to layout for all of its absolute-position descendants, **fixed-position descendants**, and descendant fixed background attachments.<sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering)</sup>

So transform is creating a containing block for fixed position element and `will-change` should do the same and since the `.parent` is now the containing block of the fixed element it will also apply its overflow on it.

Basically you can do nothing if you cannot remove the `will-change` property or change its value from `.parent`