# Child element positioned fixed relative to viewport

Tags: html, css, css-position

Is there any documentation that specifies what the default behaviour is for an element with position fixed, inside an element with position relative, absolute or static?

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;  /* or absolute/static */
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.child {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

My own experiance is that it is positioned relative to the browser viewport (unless transform is used, or left/top is omitted in child), but how can i justify that this should always will be the case? How do i know if any browsers renders this differently? Perhaps positioning the child relative to the parent, or maybe not showing the element at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position of the parent element or any ancestor is irrelevant when it comes to `position:fixed`. From [the specification:](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#fixed-positioning)

> Fixed positioning is a subcategory of absolute positioning. The only difference is that for a fixed positioned box, the containing block is established **by the viewport**.

But there is some special cases where the containing block can change. It happens when using `filter` like [I explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52937708/8620333),  `transform` like [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15194313/8620333) and sometimes `will-change` ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53679972/8620333))

---

Concerning the use of top/left/bottom/right you need to consider the static position. If you don't set any of those values the browser will consider the static position to place the element. Still From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width):

> For the purposes of this section and the next, the term "static position" (of an element) refers, roughly, **to the position an element would have had in the normal flow**. More precisely ...

A `position:fixed` element always consider the viewport as its containing block (the reference for its placement) unless there is some particular properties used in a upper level (transform, filter, etc). The position of that element is either defined by top/left/right/bottom or by the static position like described in the specification.

Related question to get more details about the static position: [Why aren't my absolutely-positioned elements located where I expect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54774549/8620333)